How to Parameterize Continuous Piecewise Linear (CPwL) Functions of 2 Variables with $k$ Pieces
Some Context: Given any CPwL function $f(x)$, I take it there is a well-defined notion of (maximal) number of pieces on each of which it's affine. For instance, if I'm not mistaken $f(x) = \|x\|_{\ell^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)}$ has $2d$ pieces, since it is the maximum of the $2d$ affine functions $f_1,\ldots,f_{2d}$ given by $f_{2j-1}(x) = x_j$ and $f_{2j}(x) = -x_j$ ($j=1,\ldots,d$). I imagine that for generic (namely, non-convex) CPwL functions, the number of pieces may be difficult to compute.
My Question: Suppose I'm interested in only the CPwL functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with $k$ pieces. Call this set of functions $\Sigma_k(\mathbb{R}^d) \subset C(\mathbb{R}^d)$, just to have something to call it. For simplicity, let's take $d=2$. How can I describe $\Sigma_k(\mathbb{R}^2)$ in terms of finitely many real parameters (possibly with restrictions on those parameters)? More precisely, given $k$, what is an explicit, continuous bijection from a subset of $\mathbb{R}^p$ onto $\Sigma_k(\mathbb{R}^2)$ (and what's $p$)?
Further Thoughts: I would hope that this is approximation theory 101... For reference, we can certainly parameterize $\Sigma_k(\mathbb{R}^1)$. See, for instance, Theorem 24.1 in http://www.cambridge.org/9781316518885, which describes $\Sigma_{n+1}(\mathbb{R}^1)$ using $2(n+1)$ parameters (image below for convenience). Intuitively, you have $2(n+1)$ degrees of freedom to describe $n+1$ affine functions. There are $n$ continuity constraints (one for each break point), so you lose $n$ degrees of freedom, but then you have $n$ more degrees of freedom from the location of each break point, so you regain the $n$ degrees of freedom lost by continuity constraints.


